# Is the System.Resources.Resourcemanager thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, resourcemanager, httpcontext.cache

My web application, when users login using different culture, is rendering it's content partially in incorrect culture.

This Asp.net web application caches the ResourceManager in the HttpContext.Current.Cache. The Resourcemanager GetString is internally using a Hashtable to store/ retrieve the resource strings.

How thread-safe is the ResourceManager?

Comment: "This type is thread safe." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety), it is thread safe.

The MSDN documentation is a great source for information and generally covers most questions. 
I'd suggest looking there first, next time. They're usually the first hit when Googling.

You can always add site:learn.microsoft.com to the query :)

Comment: Thanks Simon. I did check this before posting the question. The issue is strange that despite the thread safety, incorrect culture text is rendered to the user. I was hoping to get a different view/ solution around the HttpContext.Current.Caching as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like a different bug altogether.
The thread.safety of an object shouldn't result in that behaviour. Something else in your code is misbehaving.